# What is the purpose of these capacitors connected directly to the OpAmp output?

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, capacitance, voltage-reference

I am studying this schematic and I come across the following section:
[image]

As can shown capacitors are connected directly between the Op-Amp output to the supply (5V). What is the purpose of these capacitors, and would they not make the op-amp circuit oscillate, given that the max C load of the Op-Amp is not specified, indicating that it is not designed for high C load?

Comment: Maybe you should show us the entire schematic.

Comment: @Rohat Kılıç  Other parts of the schematic is not related to this circuit

Comment: "Other parts are not related" means `Vref`, `VDD` and `GND` are not connected to anywhere else in the circuit. Show us a bigger schematic, at least where `Vref` connects to.

Comment: @Zhi - If it doesn't make sense to you, and you are appealing for help, never, ever respond to a request for more information by saying, in effect, "you don't need to know that".

Comment: please add a reference to the source of the schematic diagram into your question ... **do not** add comment

Comment: This is a common circuit for creating a virtual earth at half the Vcc voltage. Apart from when powering up, the output of the opamp should not change appreciably and the added capacitance helps this.

Answer (score 1):

The [data sheet](https://www.run-ic.com/en/upload/goods/20230926/202309261415521554.pdf) says this about capacitive loading: -

[image]

So, you should not load it higher than this unless you absolutely know what you are doing.